# POSTing an unescaped JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to POST some JSON data to be processed by PHP.
When it arrives on the server-side, the data is escaped and I can't reliably unescape it.

```
    var jsondata = '{"name":"Foo","email":"name@address.com"},{"name":"Bar","email":"name@address.com"}';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        data: { json: '['+jsondata+']'},
    });
```

`$_POST['json']` then contains:

```
[{\"name\":\"Foo\",\"email\":\"name@address.com\"},{\"name\":\"Foo\",\"email\":\"name@address.com\"}]
```

How can I send unencoded JSON post-data? I thought `processData: false` would cover that.

---

To illustrate the error server-side:

```
<?php

$_POST['json-bad'] = '[{\"name\":\"Foo\",\"email\":\"name@address.com\"},{\"name\":\"Foo\",\"email\":\"name@address.com\"}]';
$data_bad = json_decode($_POST['json-bad']);
var_dump($data_bad); // returns "NULL"

$_POST['json-good'] = '[{"name":"Foo","email":"name@address.com"},{"name":"Bar","email":"name@address.com"}]';
$data_good = json_decode($_POST['json-good']);
var_dump($data_good); // returns array as expected

?>
```

Comment: If it can't be directly decoded by [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php), did you try to [`strip_slashes()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stripslashes.php) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing already, but it breaks badly if the data contains a double-quote. Such quotes *should* be escaped.

Comment: Couldn't you pass a real JS object ? Or define a real object and use [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) to convert it.

Comment: Is this array of JSON objects not a JS object in itself?

Comment: Where is the JSON being generated? Your example shows it hard-coded. Is it a form?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: No, returns `null`, unfortunately. It would work if the data were passed unescaped/unencoded.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming out of a form, you'll want to use some of the code below, if not all of it. This code takes a jquery form object and will `stringify` it in an appropriate fashion where you can easily do something like

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['json'], true); 
echo $json['email'];
```

Here is the JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    dataType: "json", //NOTE: indicates data type being RETURNED, not PASSED
    processData: false,
    data: { json: getJson( $('#formId') )} //NOTE: REMOVE THIS EXTRA COMMA
});


function getJson(o){
    return (JSON.stringify(o.serializeObject()));   
}
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

NOTE: Older browsers require you to inclide the `json2.js` library found here: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

Answer (score 0):

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is simply the way to express an object in javascript format.

I have the impression that you simply need to pass an object from javascript to your server.

In that case you should not need to do any specific manipulation

```
persons = {"name":"Foo","email":"name@address.com"},{"name":"Bar","email":"name@address.com"};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    data: {'persons': persons},
});
```

In server side

```
echo $_POST['persons'][0]['name'];
```

you will get

```
Foo
```

Isn't it what you are trying to do ?